# WooCommerce: Show stock status on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show the stock status for every product in cart with the status "few in stock".

Like this:

> **Productname**
>
> Size: L
>
> Only 4 left  *<- this is new*

I found a snippet to show the stock status on shop pages:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_stock_shop', 10 );

function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
   global $product;
   echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
}
```

Source: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-stock-quantity-on-shop-page/

I tried to change the hook from `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` to `woocommerce_after_cart_item_name` to display the status below the title in the cart.
But the snippet doesn't work.

Also I have no idea how to limit it to items with a low stock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try below code in function.php file

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'showing_stock_in_cart_items', 99, 3 );

function showing_stock_in_cart_items( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key  ) {
    // The WC_Product object
    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    if (empty($product)) {
        return $item_name;
    }

    // Get the  stock
    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    // When stock doesn't exist
    if (empty($stock)) {
        return $item_name;
    }

   // display the stock
   if ($stock <= '50') :
      $item_name .='<br><p style="color:green;" class="product-stock">'.__( "only " .$stock. " left","woocommerce").'</p>';
   endif;

    return $item_name;
}
```

also refer action and filter hook:-[documentation here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

Comment: Thanks, I added an extra check for the stock quantity to display the message only if it's under 50. Otherwise it will always show the message.

Comment: A little side note: Adding code snippets to functions.php is usually not a good idea since these edits will be lost when the theme is updated. Also, making errors can lock you out of your website. Only edit a functions.php if you have a child theme and the code snippet will be used within the active child theme. More information about Child Themes can be found in the Wordpress docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/